# Facebook total user count

Tags: facebook, api

Does Facebook have an API method that displays the total number of users registered on the website? Or is there any way to get a live tally of this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't publicly available data, the only information is on the press site. https://www.facebook.com/press/info.php?statistics

Comment: It's actually a hard number to work out, things are sharded across lots of databases and there is a huge difference as accounts are disabled and created each day.